# Read a file of any extension in iOS app directory with swift lang

Tags: ios, file, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

it's possible read a file with any extension that i've added to Xcode 6.1 for iOS app? there are particular actions to add in Xcode IDE environment ?
i've tray with this snippet, it read only it write, but if i would read another file it failed

```
let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]
if ((dirs) != nil) {
let dir = dirs![0]; //documents directory
let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
let text = "some text"

//writing
text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

//reading
let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
}
```

and with this snippet

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
let content = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: nil)
```

finally this snippet

```
func leggiFile(nomeFile: String, tipoFile: String) -> String{
var fileManger: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
var percorso = fileManger.enumeratorAtPath(NSHomeDirectory())
for filename in percorso!{

}
var contenuto = String(contentsOfFile: nomeFile, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)


return percorso
}

var contenuto = leggiFile("file", "txt")
```

but all fail, they don't find anything file in this location, i've manually copied the file in this path but  not work, why ?
can swift read a content of file type txt or mp3 or any extension ?
and if not, there are workarounds ?

thank's very much

Comment: What do you mean "they fail"? What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mike asked, what do you mean by "they fail"? The below works perfectly in playground for me:

```
import Foundation

let file = "file.txt"
let dirs : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

if ((dirs) != nil) {
    let dir = dirs![0]; //documents directory
    let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
    let text = "some text"

    //writing
    text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

    //reading
    let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
}
```